# Как логировать краш программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня скрипт питон стоит на VPS, время от времени он крашится... Везде стоят try,except, поэтому я не знаю почему. Может есть какой-то способ при ошибке логировать ее?

Comment: faulthandler, sys.excepthook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу пример из с `sys.excepthook`:

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('log', encoding='utf8'),
        logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout),
    ],
)


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    logging.critical(text)
    # QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


1 / 0
```